# How does C++ linkage works in this case?

Tags: c++, linker, libraries

I built a C++ library for making games in most known platforms and it works alright. However, I ran into a minor problem with the linker, which I can't live with myself without figuring the answer.

I have two separate classes in two separate files: `KinesisWorld` in `KinesisWorld.h` and `ASEngine` in `ASEngine.h` . Both of them have a similar behavior in terms of implementation, they encapsulate functionality provided by other libraries, `KinesisWorld` inherits and calls `Box2D` functions and `ASEngine` calls `angelscript` functions. So far so good.

Now, when I am building an application that uses my library, as long as I don't include or use `KinesisWorld`, the linker won't attempt to link the `Box2D` library. As soon as I simply include `KinesisWorld.h` somewhere in the final executable source, it immediately complains of undefined references until I add `Box2D` to the linker. This is the behavior I always known and observed with other libraries as well.

Though, with `angelscript`, without including `ASEngine.h` at all, it will always complain about undefined references to `angelscript`, even if the final executable doesn't make any reference to it whatsoever.

Any idea of what can cause such thing? I tested it on Linux 32 bit and Windows 32 bit, with GCC and Visual Studio respectively, same behavior.

Comment: The library functions you are calling can have non-inline calls to functions from another library, in which case you must link both.

Comment: That is not the case if i understood your statement correctly. My executable code does not include or link any of the mentioned files. It calls nothing, but rather includes the "engine" as a static library. ASEngine and KinesisWorld are identical for example , as they both call a third party library function in their constructor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker doesn't care until the offending (declared but undefined) functions are called.

In this case, you aren't using any Box2D functions anywhere except in KinesisWorld but you ARE using angelscript somewhere in your library. Double check your ASEngine facade but in particular everywhere else (using the "find" feature across your entire project might help).

Comment: Oh, so if any other .cpp file happens to call ASEngine functions, and that cpp is actually being called, it can cause the issue, I think i got it! :)